# CFRunLoopRun returns immediately in NSThread

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, notifications

I have objective C code, which I call from c++ application.
in that objective C code,when I just run CFRunLoopRun(), it stops and loops there, but when I create new

```
 NSThread* evtThread = [ [NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                               selector:@selector( saySomething )
                                                 object:nil ];

[ evtThread start ];
```

and run CFRunLoopRun() there, it returns immediately.

whats wrong?

turned out that I need some input source, so I want to run that loop in non-main thread and get notifications there, how shall I do it?

added

```
 NSRunLoop *q = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
 [q addPort:[NSMachPort port] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

before CFRunLoopRun, now it loops but dont get sleep notifications.
btw I get sleep notifications if I call it from main thread,.

Comment: What do you do in `saySomething`?  Does it execute?

Comment: yes it executes, I get logs from there but CFRunLoopRun() stops immediately

Comment: Do you have some kind of source or timer associated with the run loop?

Comment: I just use CFRunLoopRun() there, nothing else

Answer (score 2):

Note the last phrase of the documentation for `CFRunLoopRun()`:

"The current thread’s run loop runs in the default mode (see Default Run Loop Mode) until the run loop is stopped with CFRunLoopStop or all the sources and timers are removed from the default run loop mode."

It seems from your comments that you're asking a run loop in a new thread to run but haven't actually given it anything to do.

Comment: [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector( workspaceWillPowerOff: )
     name:NSWorkspaceWillPowerOffNotification
     object:[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]
     ];
    
     [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector( workspaceWillPowerOff: )
     name:NSWorkspaceWillSleepNotification
     object:[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]
     ];
    
    CFRunLoopRun();
   
    still no luck :(

Comment: looks like they dont get added or something like that?

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe that those notifications qualify as run loop sources?

Comment: I only want to receive those two notifications there, can you please tell me correct way to do it? :)

Comment: That depends....  Do you really need a separate long-running thread as opposed to just setting up your observers without doing any special threading?

Comment: (In fact, the more I think about it, creating a separate thread doesn't make a lot of sense to me since I don't see that you get to control which thread the notification is delivered on.)

Comment: but there has to be a thread that will run a loop where those notifications will be delivered right? I just want background thread, that will catch those notifications

Comment: I have some app in c++, I want to get sleep notifications in it, is there any other way? I have to either create thread in c++ and call that code from there or call code that will create thread in objective c and return immediately, leaving running thread that will monitor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67552/discussion-between-jani-baramidze-and-phillip-mills).

Comment: Notification delivery has nothing to do with runloops. NSNotifications are synchronously delivered on the thread they are posted on. `-postNotification` doesn't put something on a queue; it immediately calls all the observers. As @PhillipMills indicates, there is no reason to create a thread here at all. Just register for the notification on the main queue. If you need to process on a background queue, use `dispatch_async` (which can call C++ if you need that).